# How to update ACR password in the Azure container app secrets without using UI?

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-container-apps, defaultazurecredential

As we have more than 50 container apps that require ACR password updates, doing it through UI is a very long task.

I tried to create a Makefile which uses the `az` cli tool to get the secret name and update with new password. Note, the secret name was auto-created when container app is created.

While running the below command,

`az containerapp secret set -n MyApp -g MyRG --secrets reg-pswd-abcd1234-ab12=MySecretToken`
where *reg-pswd-abcd1234-ab12* is the name of the secret automatically generated upon the app's creation

getting the following error:

> Secret names cannot be longer than 20. Please shorten
> reg-pswd-abcd1234-ab12

Question:

1. Is there any other workaround to update this secret value?

or

2. Create a new secret value and replace the reference of the old secret name with a newer one?

Comment: Try the this command to update secrets using Keyvault: az containerapp secret set -n MyContainerapp -g MyResourceGroup --secrets MySecretName1=MySecretValue1 MySecretName2=keyvaultref:https://example.vault.azure.net/secrets/mysecret,identityref:/subscriptions/sub/resourceGroups/rg/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/myidentity  : [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/containerapp/secret?view=azure-cli-latest#az-containerapp-secret-set)

Comment: @VenkatV *reg-pswd-abcd1234-ab12* contains the azure container registry password and whenever I try to update the azure container app with `az containerapp revision copy ...` command, it internally try to find the password from the auto created secret. How can I update that reference after setting the new key with keyvaultref?

Comment: If I update the current secret with keyvaultref, it will throw the same error, as the secret name is longer than 20 characters.

Comment: Refer the same qns in Github: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-container-apps/issues/728, As of now 20 characters are not allowed.

Comment: @VenkatV Yes, that is true, but Is there any other workaround to update this secret value?
or

Create a new secret value and replace the reference of the old secret name with a newer one?

Comment: @VenkatV [Here](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-container-apps/issues/209#issuecomment-1673937022), someone says, that it was updated to 63 characters, but till facing an error. Do you have any updates on this?

Comment: I am able to update a password that had more than 20 characters now. Here is my [result](https://i.imgur.com/Ic9O2MY.png)

Comment: @VenkatV Can you try to rename `test` to `testabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`, which is more than 20 characters, and try to update the secret value? Name of key should be greater than 20 characters.

Comment: Name is not accepting more than 20 but value is accepting.

Comment: @VenkatV Yes, ACR is creating a secret name with more than 20 characters by default, when I try to update it's value through command, it was not accepting it, getting the above error.